# debsums check shows missing files

Tags: package-management

I am using Kubuntu 20.10 and I ran sudo apt-get clean, then sudo deebsums -cs to see if there is anything amiss in my system, it's been running very slowly recently. It came up with:
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/7b/d44d19c62527b5e3ee6b258c8f83352a5078b7.debug (from libc6-dbg:amd64 package)
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/llvm-10/build/utils/lit/tests/.coveragerc (from llvm-10-tools package)
Please advise.

Comment: How do the checksums in any way affect the speed?

Comment: The two do not appear to be related, but there may be common issues. I those missing files could be restored, it could do no harm perhaps it may do some good somewhere.